# JTextPane and foreground color

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtextpane, foreground

want to have a JTextPane whose content can always be selected by the user. Therefore I created my own subclass of JTextPane and always return true in the method "isEnabled()". Additionally I introduce a new member m_enabled which is responsible for returning the correct foreground color (enabled/disabled).

It works as expected, but if I set a default foreground color (e.g. Color.RED) and toggle between enabled and disabled, the foreground color won't be red anymore.

Can you help me to solve this issue?

```
public class StylesExample1 {
public static final String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor...";
public static boolean m_enabled = true;

public static void main(String[] args) throws BadLocationException {
    try {
        UIManager
                .setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception evt) {
    }

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame");
    final JTextPane pane = new MyPane();
    pane.setText(text);

    pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    f.getContentPane().add(pane);
    JButton b = new JButton("Toggle Enabled state");
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            m_enabled = !m_enabled;
            System.err.println("setting textpane enabled to " + m_enabled);
            pane.setEnabled(m_enabled);
        }
    });

    pane.setForeground(Color.red);

    f.getContentPane().add(b);
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.setSize(400, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}

class MyPane extends JTextPane {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private boolean m_enabled = true;
private Color defaultForegroundColor, disabledTextColor;

public MyPane() {
    defaultForegroundColor = getForeground();
    disabledTextColor = getDisabledTextColor();
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    m_enabled = enabled;

    if (m_enabled) {
        setForeground(defaultForegroundColor);
    } else {
        setForeground(disabledTextColor);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- your class class `MyPane extends JTextPane` doesn't override specifics and proper methods required for `WindowsLookAndFeel`,
- there could be another issues with `DeafultHightLigter/Painter/Caret/Selection`
- (I'd suggest) use and override key in UIManager for `Windows(Classic)LookAndFeel`
- EDIT list of keys from [UIManager by @camickr](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/)

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

public class StylesExample1 {

    private final String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor...";
    private boolean m_enabled = true;

    public StylesExample1() {
        final JTextPane pane = new MyPane();
        pane.setText(text);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        JButton b = new JButton("Toggle Enabled state");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                m_enabled = !m_enabled;
                System.err.println("setting textpane enabled to " + m_enabled);
                pane.setEnabled(m_enabled);
            }
        });
        pane.setDisabledTextColor(Color.red);
        pane.setForeground(Color.red);
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(pane);
        f.add(b);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.setSize(400, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BadLocationException {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception evt) {
        }
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new StylesExample1();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyPane extends JTextPane {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean m_enabled = true;
    private Color defaultForegroundColor, disabledTextColor;

    public MyPane() {
        defaultForegroundColor = getForeground();
        disabledTextColor = getDisabledTextColor();
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        m_enabled = enabled;
        if (m_enabled) {
            UIManager.put("TextPane.disabledBackground", Color.RED);
            UIManager.put("TextPane.foreground", Color.RED);
            UIManager.put("TextPane.inactiveForeground", Color.RED);
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this); // don't to use this
        } else {
            UIManager.put("TextPane.disabledBackground", Color.RED);
            UIManager.put("TextPane.foreground", Color.RED);
            UIManager.put("TextPane.inactiveForeground", Color.RED);
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this); // don't to use this
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my usecase I need to change the background color afterwards. So I dont want to hardcode the red color. It should be possible to to adjust it later on

Comment: you can pass any (valid value for) Color instead of Color.RED, simple you can to use defaultForegroundColor / disabledTextColor, via constructor or as hardcoded constants (enum) initialized in local variable, and to use private variables, now your question is about/only how to pass value from another class (daily asked in Swing)

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor for "MyPane", you're setting the default foreground colour to the default foreground for JTextPane, but then after the constructor you're calling setForeground(Color.red). The issue is the "defaultForegroundColor" member in MyPane doesn't know it's meant to be red. Make the following adjustments:

```
public MyPane(Color defaultForegroundColor)
{
  this.defaultForegroundColor = defaultForegroundColor;
  this.disabledTextColor = getDisabledTextColor();
}
```

and create it using the following code:

```
final JTextPane pane = new MyPane(Color.red);
```

If you want to change the foreground after construction, do the following:

```
public void setNewForeground(Color c)
{
   this.defaultForegroundColor = c;
}
```

Comment: but what if I want to change the foreground color after the constructor has been called?

Comment: I've amended the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

> want to have a JTextPane whose content can always be selected by the user.

Then I would use:

```
setEditable( false );
```

instead of

```
setEnabled( false );
```